# Jaspersoft - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found when implementing token-based auth

Tags: jasperserver

I'm implementing the token-based authentication with Jaspersoft and follow the [docs](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-authentication-cookbook/v56/token-based-authentication). But when I restart the server it gives me the following error below.[image]

I did not do anything other than below which can be found in the docs.

To configure JasperReports Server to work with your authentication method, modify and deploy the sample configuration file as follows:

1. Make a copy of the preauth sample file in the /samples/externalAuth-sample-config/ directory and rename it to remove the sample- prefix. For example, rename sample-applicationContext-externalAuth-preauth.xml to applicationContext-externalAuth-preauth.xml.
2. Edit the file you created and configure the beans correctly for your deployment, as described in the following sections.
3. Place the modified file in the /WEB-INF directory.

I am using the TIBCO Jaspersoft community edition. This is the first time I'm using this token-based authentication so I may have missed some configurations.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Status - 404 Not Found

Resoure not found. Check your `web.xml` if you have added the page defined in the `web.xml` or default page.

Comment: If, I remove the applicationContext-externalAuth-preauth.xml everything is working.